# Updating elements in a d3 svg chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to d3 but my next project will heavily depend on interactive charts. I read introductions and understand the concept of data binding, entering elements and then exit and remove as stated in the [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218). However, I'm not sure whether it is possible to just update a few elements of an existing svg plot (previously generated with d3) without re-rendering the whole svg. Let's say I want to transform a `<g>` group or update an "x" coordinate of a `rect` element.

I aim to write a customized timeline plugin. [I started from this one](https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline). This plugin does not consider updating of data. Let's say I'd like to have a vertical bar indicating a specific time and I want to dynamically update the bar's position. Q1: do I have to draw the whole svg from scratch? In my ideal world I'd have a method `updateCursor()` on the timeline function that accepts a time string. Q2: can one achieve that? Are there any tutorials dealing with this you are aware of?

In the examples I found, updating requires re-drawing of the whole svg. E.g:
http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html

Thank you so much for answers!

Best,
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q1: do I have to draw the whole svg from scratch? In my ideal world
>   I'd have a method updateCursor() on the timeline function that accepts
>   a time string.

Absolutely **No**, you **do not need** to draw the whole thing.  You can update any piece of the svg after all they are just `dom` elements that can be selected then moved, transformed, style, etc...

> Q2: can one achieve that? Are there any tutorials dealing with this
>   you are aware of?

Tons of tutorials, in fact the general update pattern, you link above is such an example.  The key is in these lines:

```
// you've selected a bunch of text elements that already exist on the page
var text = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(data); //<-- you've now bound data to them

// text here is the elements already on the page, we just update them
text.attr("class", "update");

// if there's more data then previous existing elements
// these are returned by .enter()
text.enter().append("text")

// now you are operating on both existing and new elements
text.text(function(d) { return d; });
```

[Also, the d3 noob example, *doesn't* redraw the whole chart, it just redraws the line, after all that's what's updated]

Your situation sounds even easier, though, because it sounds like you are dealing with one element you want to re-position (and in that case you don't need data-binding).  Initially you'll do:

```
var myCoolRect = svg.append('rect')
  .attr('id', 'myCoolRect')
  .attr('x', 100)
  ....;
```

Now you can keep a reference to it and then update it later using:

```
myCoolRect.attr('x', 250);
```

Or you can re-select it later, by the unique `id` I gave it:

```
svg.select('#myCoolRect')
  .attr('x', 100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, your very last code snippet touches something I wasn't sure about all the time. I think, I tried something similar where I also needed to have access to the scale function of the d3 object. Which was not available there. So I thought, it's not possible to do something like this. Seems like I have a general misconception regarding scope, namespaces and how to organize d3 plugins...

Comment: @Toni, glad my answer helped.  As you said the a `scale` is just a plain old JavaScript function, it's scope just follows JavaScript conventions.